# Hill Cipher Encrypt

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography

So I am trying to use the hill cipher to encrypt my 3x3 matrix with a given key. It works correctly for the first value outputting n which it should, but then after that value I get large values and it never takes the mod of them. I added the cout statements to help me debug and see what's going wrong, but I still can't fix it. Also the second mod 26 is there because when I didn't have it there I was getting negative 13 instead of positive 13. This is a homework program, our key was given to us as numbers in case that is of any importance.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using std::endl;
using std::string;


void inverse_matrix();
string encryption(string x);

int main()
{
std::string one = "paymoremoney";
// inverse_matrix();

encryption(one);

system("pause");
return 0;
}



string encryption(string x)
{
int encrypted[4][4];
int key[3][3];
key[0][0] = 4;
key[0][1] = 9;
key[0][2] = 15;
key[1][0] = 15;
key[1][1] = 17;
key[1][2] = 6;
key[2][0] = 24;
key[2][1] = 0;
key[2][2] = 17;

int test = 0;
char str[] = "";
char c;


int length = (int)x.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    x[i] = tolower(x[i]);

}
/*


while (str[test])
{
    c = str[test];
    putchar(tolower(c));
    test++;

}
*/


int encrypt[4][4];
encrypt[0][0] = x[0];
encrypt[0][1] = x[1];
encrypt[0][2] = x[2];
encrypt[1][0] = x[3];
encrypt[1][1] = x[4];
encrypt[1][2] = x[5];
encrypt[2][0] = x[6];
encrypt[2][1] = x[7];
encrypt[2][2] = x[8];
encrypt[3][0] = x[9];
encrypt[3][1] = x[10];
encrypt[3][2] = x[11];



encrypted[0][0] = (key[0][0] * encrypt[0][0]) + (key[1][0] * encrypt[0][1])              + (key[3][0] * encrypt[0][2]) % 26;
encrypted[0][0] %= 26;



encrypted[0][1] = (key[0][1] * encrypt[0][0]) + (key[1][1] * encrypt[0][1]) + (key[2][1] * encrypt[0][2])%26;
encrypted[0][0] %= 26;

encrypted[0][2] = (key[0][2] * encrypt[0][0]) + (key[1][2] * encrypt[0][1]) + (key[2][2] * encrypt[0][2]) % 26;
encrypted[0][0] %= 26;

std::cout << encrypted[0][0];
std::cout << endl;
std::cout << encrypted[0][1];
std::cout << endl;
std::cout << encrypted[0][2];


std::cout << endl;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is homework, I'll point in the right direction rather than give a direct answer.  You're assigning to `encrypted[0][1]`.  What do you do with that value after assigning to it?

Comment: wow, thanks guess I needed a fresh pair of eyes. been working on the encryption and inverse all day silly mistake, thank you very much.